# Retrieve last inserted id with Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Good day,

I am willing to retrieve the id value of a freshly inserted row in Mysql.

I know there is mysqli_insert_id function, but:

1. I can't specify the table
2. Maybe there would be a risk of retrieving the wrong id, if a query is made in the meanwhile.
3. I am using node.js MySQL

I don't want to take the risk to query the highest id since there are a lot of queries, it could give me the wrong one...

(My id column is on auto-increment)

Comment: What makes you think that you have to specify the table you've inserted to to get the ID? What have you tried so far to make it work?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row
describes the solution perfectly well:

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', {title: 'test'}, function(err, result, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});
```

Comment: What if there are [multiple `insert` statements](//stackoverflow.com/q/39270007/4928642)?

Comment: What can I do if my primary key is a non-incrementing type?

I'm using uuid as a BINARY(16) for the primary key.

Comment: Hi Raghav, if your key is not auto-incrementing and not database created your should not need to retrieve it like this. After all, you should have the key already somewhere in your programming logic. If you struggle, I would suggest you create an independent question about this here on SO.

Comment: @luksch uuid() is a function of mysql, created on the database, he doesn't know what the uuid is until the insert into statement is called.

Comment: when i use console.log(result.insertId). It work good. But when send response.send(result.insertId)it throws errors. Why it is?

Comment: what if I'm working with stored procedures, my insertedId is always 0...

Comment: It's been a while since this was posted but I am having the same issue. In my case `console.log(result.insertId);` returns undefined. Could you please help me as well?

Comment: @Valamorde I currently do not use nodejs any more, so I would suggest you create a new question here describing exactly what the problem is. My guess is, that your table definition uses AUTO_INCREMENT in the id column, but your primary key is a composite key? see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: @valamorde You have to `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: @Qwertiy: if you have multiple insert statements you need to retrieve the last record ID after each insert statement

Comment: I am trying to resolve() a Promise with the insertId and it gives me node:internal/validators:119 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type number (4)

Answer (score 12):

```
var table_data =  {title: 'test'};

connection_db.query('INSERT INTO tablename SET ?', table_data , function(err, result, fields) {
  if (err) {
      // handle error
    }else{
       // Your row is inserted you can view  
      console.log(result.insertId);
    }
});
```

You can also view by visiting this link https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

Answer (score -2):

I think you misunderstood the use of `mysqli_insert_id()` method. This method must be executed **immediately** after the insert statement to obtain the last inserted id. if you do it my MySQL directly

```
INSERT INTO(a,b)values(1,'test');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();  -- this will display the last inserted id
```