# Can't pass data between native promises when "looping" them

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm having problems trying to "loop" into multiple "nested" promises with native JS.

I have a JSON with many sublevels as shown:

```
{
    "project": {
        "name": "TESTNAME",
        "label":"string11405",
        "description":"das",
    },
    "form": [{
        "label": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "fields": [{
            "label": "string",
            "name": "string",
            "field_type_id": "string",
            "meta": [{
                "meta_name": "string",
                "meta_value": "string"
            }]
       }]
}
```

So I have checked that I need to use `Promise.all`.

```
    return Promise.all(_.map(req.crfData ,(value,index,arr) => {
        var table = 'TABLE1';

        return conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${table} SET ?`,[value]);
    }))
    .then((result) => {
        var table = 'TABLE2';

        return Promise.all(_.map(req.fieldData ,(value,index,arr) => {
            value.crf_id = result.insertId;
            return conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${table} SET ?`,[value]);
        }));
    })
    .then((result) => {
        var table = 'TABLE3';

        return Promise.all(_.map(req.fieldData ,(value,index,arr) => {
            return conn.query(`INSERT INTO ${table} SET ?`,[value[0]],(err) => next(err));
        }));
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
```

The problem comes with the second query (TABLE2) where I can't retrieve the mysql new id from the previous promise because `result` contains a promise and not the appropiate data should be returned.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would expect the `result` to contain data from the first query.  What is the `conole.log` of that result var?

Comment: `result` contains an array with the results of the individual promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Using_Promise.all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `result` argument will be an array of whatever `conn.query()` resolves with (that's what `Promise.all()` resolves with).  So, `result.insertId` will be `undefined` since `result` is an array, not an object with named properties.

`.insertId` will be a property on each individual array element of `result`.  If you want to read it from the last result returned by the previous query, then you would use something like this:

```
result[result.length - 1].insertId
```

Which is consistent with how `.insertId` is set for a single INSERT operation as shown here [Return last inserted id with mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31371153/816620).