# Best Approach to a 3 Table Update for Tagging System in NodeJS and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm writing an application that let's a user post content (called "moments") along with one or more tags associated with that content.

I have a 3 table data model (in MySQL) that looks like this:

- Table: MOMENTS, Columns: MOMENT_ID, USER_ID, TITLE, CREATE_DATE
- Table: TAGS, Columns: TAG_ID, TITLE, CREATE_DATE
- Table: MOMENTS_TAGS, Columns: MOMENT_ID, TAG_ID

Auto-Increment is set for: MOMENT_ID and TAG_ID

**The problem I'm trying to solve (in NodeJS) is: how do I insert a new post (in MOMENT table) and 1 or more tags (in TAGS table), get their respective ID's and do a 3rd insert into the junction table (MOMENT_TAGS)?**

I've already attempted to solve this (using mysqljs) by doing 3 successive queries, first MOMENTS, then TAGS, then MOMENTS_TAGS, but it fails because although the first result1.insertId returns the correct number, the 2nd result2.insertId doesn't seem to return the correct number from the TAGS table and instead simply increments the first result1.insertId.

Here is my code so far (I'm trying to get this to work for 1 tag at first):

```
app.post('/api/post/complex', function(req,res) {

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

    var preppedQuery1 = "INSERT INTO MOMENTS (USER_ID, TITLE, CREATE_DATE) VALUES ('justatest@gmail.com','test moment title','2016-08-08')";
    connection.query(preppedQuery1, function(err1, result1) { 

      if (err1) {
        res.send('ERROR');  
        connection.release();
      } 
      else {

        var preppedQuery2 = "INSERT INTO TAGS (TITLE, CREATE_DATE,USER_ID) VALUES ('TEST TAG', '2016-09-08','justatest@gmail.com')";
        connection.query(preppedQuery1, function(err2, result2) {  

        if (err2) {
          res.send('ERROR');  
          connection.release();
        } 
        else {

          var preppedQuery3 = "INSERT INTO MOMENTS_TAGS (MOMENT_ID, TAG_ID) VALUES (" + result1.insertId + "," + result2.insertId + ")";
          //At this point if result.insertId is 100, result2.insertId is always 101 instead of coming from the TAGS table
          //Why isn't result2.insertId the auto-incremented number from the TAGS table insert?

connection.query(preppedQuery3, function(err3, result3) {  

            if (err3) {         
              res.send('ERROR');
              connection.release();  
            } 
            else {
              console.log(result3); //not really needed
              res.send('OK'); //everything worked
              connection.release();

            }

          });

        }

        });

      } 

    });

  });

});
```

Comment: get the last inserted id after each insert into a variable so you can use it in the other inserts here is a SO question on the subject. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371079/retrieve-last-inserted-id-with-mysql

Comment: Matt - I tried that and for some reason the 2nd variable containing the 2nd insertID is just the first variable + 1. Strange that it doesn't seem to get the insertID from the 2nd table (TAGS).

Comment: I would recommend updating your question with your new attempt so that I and others can see/help troubleshoot the new error/issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're running `preppedQuery1` twice.

Typo here:

[image: typo]

(Assuming that's not just a typo in the post and actually exists in your source...)

Comment: You're right user866762. I figured this out just a bit ago and was pretty annoyed. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Sweet. Mind accepting either your own answer or mine so this stops showing up in unanswered questions?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: typo in 2nd preppedQuery (used 1 again, instead of 2).

Tested things and correct insertId is being assigned.