# Inserting last inserted ID into foreign key field with Express, NodeJS, MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When a contact form is submitted, by the database design I was provided with, the customer e-mail and name should go into `customerinfo` table, while their message goes into `questionrecord` table. The foreign key in `questionrecord` table references the CustomerID in `customerinfo` table, which is an Auto-incrementing Primary key. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371079/retrieve-last-inserted-id-with-mysql) , I found that the last inserted ID can be retrieved on the results variable and I found it viable to be inserted as the foreign key value for the row to be inserted in `questionrecord`.

I then wrote the code below in hopes of inserting to `customerinfo` table first, then retrieve the last inserted id and insert it as the foreign key to the new `questionrecord` record.

But it leads to the error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I assume I cannot call query() twice in the same Express route? How can I perform something similar?

I had thought of redirecting the post request to another route which handles inserting into `questionrecord` table separately but I have no way to send the value of the last inserted ID along with the redirect.

```
app.post('/inquiryPost', (req, res) => {
    let newCustomer = {CustomerEmail: req.body.inqEmail, CustomerName: req.body.fullName};
    
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO customerinfo SET ?';
    let lastInsertId;
    console.log(newCustomer)
    con.query(sql, newCustomer, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            lastInsertID = result.insertId;
        } else {
            res.send("failed to insert into customerinfo table");
        }
    })

    let newQuestion = {CustomerID: lastInsertId, CustomerConcern: req.body.contactMsg};
    let sql2 = 'INSERT INTO questionrecord SET ?';
    con.query(sql2, newQuestion, (err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            res.sendFile("../SE-Metro-Q/contact.html")
        } else {
            res.send("failed to insert into customerinfo table");
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: you both insert a run paralelel, you need fiirst to wait for the new id and then insert the second

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)