# How can I see the result of what I save into the "MySQL" database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-insert, mysql2

I have the following function that works fine and saves the new user data into the database:

```
  static async create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
    await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password, admin) VALUES(?,?,?)",
      [req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.admin])
      .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json(("user created successfully"));
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); next(); });
  }
```

But when I try to change the following line:

```
await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
```

Like this:

```
const user = await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
```

Or change this line:

```
.then(() => {
```

To

```
.then((user) => { res.send(user);
```

In none of the cases I can't read the value of `user` and it's `undefined`. Is there a simple way that after I save a user into the database, I get a response with the saved user information inside the database?

EDIT: The configuration for the database looks like thie below code:

```
import mysql from "mysql2";

const pool =  mysql.createPool(
  {
  host : (process.env.DB_HOST),
  user : (process.env.DB_USER),
  password:  (process.env.DB_PASSWORD ),
  database: (process.env.DB_NAME ),
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
  }).promise();
```

Comment: Is this using `mysql2` or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve last inserted id with Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31371079/283366)

Comment: @Phil: `mysql2`

Comment: What data are you missing for `user` that isn't present in `req.body`? Are you just after the generated ID?