# How can I see the result of MySQL "INSERT" operation in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, response, sql-insert, mysql2

I am creating a new user using the following code:

```
  static async create(user: IUser) : Promise<IUser | undefined> {
    const rows: any = await Pools.execute(
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password, username , admin) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
      [user.email, user.password, user.username, user.admin]);
    try {
      console.log('created user' , rows[0]);

      if (!rows[0] || !rows[0].length)
        return;
      return;

    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

But the result for `console.log('created user' , rows[0]);` is:

```
created user ResultSetHeader {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 17,
  info: '',
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningStatus: 0
}
```

Also when I call the function like `const createduser = await Users.create(user);`  the result still is like:

```
createduser undefined
```

How can I get the result of new created user back as an `IUser` object?

Comment: Perform a query to retrieve it, like with regular SQL?

Comment: @robertklep: Should I create a new query like `const newUser: any = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [user.email]);` or there is a way to add this new SQL command to previous one?

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question. This is a duplicate of [How can I see the result of what I save into the "MySQL" database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025086/how-can-i-see-the-result-of-what-i-save-into-the-mysql-database). You could start by responding to the questions you were asked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it seems there is no way to get new created user at a one shot and I should add another query afterwards and change the code like below:

```
  static async create(user: IUser){
    const rows: any = await Pools.execute(
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password, username , admin) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
      [user.email, user.password, user.username, user.admin]);
      const newUser: any = await Pools.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [user.email]);
    try {
      if (!newUser[0] || !newUser[0].length)
        return;
      return newUser[0][0];

    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This will only work correctly when the `user.email` is a unique value in your database.

Comment: @Luuk: Yes, that is!

Comment: @Luuk: If you know a better way of doind that please add a new answer.

Comment: It was just meant as a warning to those people who only copy/paste _solutions_ from stackoverflow, Or those who ask a new (same) question, when the answer is not suited for them.